# Seventy-two Years of Chevlei Mashiach

Tags: sources-mekorot, messiah

Has anyone heard that the birth pangs of *Mashiach* will last seventy-two years?

Comment: Sounds arbitrarily similar to how many years since the state of Israel was formed. What makes you think 72 is a relevant number to the chevlei moshiach?

Comment: תיפח רוחם של מחשבי קיצים

Comment: Based off what do you ask your question?

Answer (score -1):

There are several places where the concept of **70 years** are being brought down. 72 years however, I am not completely sure.

The Vilna Gaon says that there are 70 words in the Psalm 20, which we recite daily at the end of shacharis.

See this article on [Torch: Torah Weekly](https://www.torchweb.org/torah_detail.php?id=180)

> The Vilna Gaon in Yahel Ohr (2:119:2) notes that there are **seventy** words in this Psalm, corresponding to the **seventy years of travails and suffering**  referred to in the classic texts as the birth pangs of Messiah - that the Jewish people will have to experience before the Messiah comes and redeems us (emphasis mine)

The Gra mentions this in his סידור הגר"א (Siddur), see picture below, property of [HebrewBooks.org](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42980&st=&pgnum=282)

[image]

And [Rabbi Daniel Yaakov Travis explains:](https://rabbitravis.org/the-end-of-the-world-as-we-know-it/)

> The answer to this question is found in the Siddur HaGra (Lamnatze’ach), citing the Vilna Gaon’s commentary on the Zohar (Vol. II 119b): “The 70 words of Lamnatze’ach allude to the 70 years of chevlei Moshiach. The ram screams out in seventy different voices. This represents the days of tribulation, and from them [the nation] will be redeemed.”

Comment: Please do not quote Christian sites advocating for belief in Jesus here. Sources matter.

Comment: It popped up during my search, did not know it until you mentioned it.

Comment: You have to be more responsible. I'm sure you will be in future.